# On an inequality concerning vectors with norm less than one

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Consider two sets of vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{n_1}$ and $\{w_j\}_{j=1}^{n_2}$ with $v_i,w_j\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|v_i\|_2< 1$ and $\|w_j\|_2< 1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n_1$ and $j=1,\dots,n_2$. Does the following inequality hold
$$
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n_1}\prod_{j=1}^{n_2}(1-v_i^{\top}w_j)^2}{\prod_{i=1}^{n_1}\prod_{j=1}^{n_1}(1-v_i^\top v_j)\prod_{i=1}^{n_2}\prod_{j=1}^{n_2}(1-w_i^\top w_j)}\geq 1 \quad ?
$$

So far I didn't manage to find a way to prove or disprove it, however numerical simulations suggest that it is likely to be true. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What progress have you made? Can you prove it when $n_1=n_2=1$? when $n_1=1$ and $n_2=2$? when $n_1=n_2$ and $v_i=w_i$?

Comment: @GregMartin: When $n_1=n_2$ and $v_i=w_i$ it is easy to see that the inequality is satisfied with equality. For the other cases I don't have an answer. Concerning the general case, I carried out a large number of simulations (using randomly generated $v_i$ and $w_i$) and no counterexamples showed up yet.